# How to return an argument to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
  function increment(index, type) {
    $scope.items[index].type++;
    console.log(type);
    console.log($scope.items[index].type);
  };
```

When I do `console.log(type)` I get the string right.

However, `console.log($scope.items[index].type)` returns a `NaN`.

Any idea how to add an argument to a list of array?

Comment: The phrase "add an argument to a list of array" does not make sense. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: So `type` is a string? So, what are you trying to accomplish with the `++`?

Comment: These are two different Objects... What about $scope.items.push(thingYouWantToAdd)?

Comment: you know - 2nd argument in your function is not used, right?

Comment: is your `type` a dynamic property? try `$scope.items[index][type]++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `type` is a string then neither

```
$scope.items[index].type++;
```

or

```
console.log($scope.items[index].type);
```

Will do what you're expecting.

You will need to use `type` as an array/object index.

```
function increment(index, type) {
    $scope.items[index][type]++;
    console.log(type);
    console.log($scope.items[index][type]);
};
```

Comment: You have got one extra `.` there after `[index]`

Comment: `$scope.items[index].[type]` should be `$scope.items[index][type]` (without the dot)

Comment: Thanks guys, removed the extra dot `.`

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the needed info. Please provide the structure of your items array and stuff.

But if I read your code I can assume that type is somehow an attribute of each item in the array. So this works fine....

```js
let items = [{type: 5}, {type: 6}, {type: 7}];

increment(2, "no clue what this argument is about");

function increment(index, type) {
    items[index].type++;
    document.write(type);
    document.write("<br/>" + items[index].type);
 };
```